# Storing negative number in an unsigned int

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, unsigned-integer

I have access to a program which I'm running which SHOULD be guessing a very low number for certain things and outputting the number (probably 0 or 1). However, 0.2% of the time when it should be outputting 0 it outputs a number from 4,294,967,286 - 4,294,967,295. (Note: the latter is the max number an unsigned integer can be).

What I GUESS is happening is the function is guessing the number of the data to be less than 0 aka -1 to -9 and when it assigns that number to an unsigned int it's wrapping the number around to be the max or close to the max number.

I therefore assumed the program is written in C (I do not have access to the source code) and then tested in Visual Studio .NET 2012 C what would happen if I assign a variety of negative numbers to an unsigned integer. Unfortunately, nothing seemed to happen - it would still output the number to the console as a negative integer. I'm wondering if this is to do with MSVS 2012 trying to be smart or perhaps some other reason.

Anyway, am I correct in assuming that this is in fact what is happening and the reason why the programs outputs the max number of an unisnged int? Or are there any other valid reasons as to why this is happening?

Edit: All I want to know is if it's valid to assume that attempting to assign a negative number to an unsigned integer can result in setting the integer to the max number aka 4,294,967,295. If this is IMPOSSIBLE then okay, I'm not looking at SPECIFICS on exactly why this is happening with the program as I do not have access to the code. All I want to know is if it's possible and therefore a possible explanation as to why I am getting these results.

Comment: Like I said - I do not have access to the source code of the program. Unless you're saying I am correct in assuming the above and you want to see my code to see why it's also not outputting the number 4,294,967,295?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about making guesses about a binary program we don't have access to.

Comment: Mate all I want to know is if this is a likely reason as to why this is happening - and if there are any other common explanations. I know how to use a debugger - I also don't have access to the program itself, only the output.

Comment: " it would still output the number to the console as a negative integer. " - I'd guess you are causing undefined behaviour by using `%d` with `printf` for an unsigned int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++ assigning -1 to an unsigned number will give you the maximum unsigned value.

This is guaranteed by the standard and all compilers I know (even VC) implement this part correctly. Probably your C example has some other problem for not showing this result (cannot say without seeing the code).

Comment: Thanks my good man - this is all I wanted to know. Can you explain as to why my question deserves -3 and a comment saying how it's off topic? I don't understand what's wrong with it. I was curious to how something works related to programming so I thought this was a good place to post.

Comment: Your question invited a discussion and speculation about the source. That is not within the format of stackoverflow... as weird as that may sometimes sound. I will +1 you just to offset the negative points.

Comment: @Mitchell: I don't see anything wrong with the question (except that has been replicated a few times in slightly different forms). Posting your test code would have allowed to show why you didn't get the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of negative numbers to have its first bit counting negative.

A 4 bit integer would be

```
Binary       HEX      INT4          UINT4
(In Memory)           (As decimal)  (As decimal)
0000         0x0      0             0 (UINT4_MIN)
0001         0x1      1             1
0010         0x2      2             2
0100         0x4      4             4
0111         0x7      7 (INT4_MAX)  7
1000         0x8      -8 (INT4_MIN) 8
1111         0xF      -1            15 (UINT4_MAX)
```

It may be that the header of a library lies to you and the value is negative.

If the library has no other means of telling you about errors this may be a deliberate error value. I have seen "nonsensical" values used in that manner before.
The error could be calculated as `(UINT4_MAX - error)` or always UINT4_MAX if an error occurs.

Really, without any source code this is a guessing game.

EDIT: 
I expanded the illustrating table a bit.
If you want to log a number like that you may want to log it in hexadecimal form. The Hex view allows you to peek into memory a bit quicker if you are used to it.